# How to change the dropdown option on a product page?

Tags: magento

I want to change the dropdown option on the product page.
Like there is a dropdown of size and I want that dropdown to change into the image icon of small, medium and large.
And when I click on the size option say small the related color images will appear below just like the default functionality of the magento.
Can anyone know how to do this

Comment: Did you look for extensions?

Comment: I did and after a very long search I found the extension. I make it work

Comment: hello which extension you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the extension developed by the Tzyganu on the GitHub. It works perfectly for changing the dropdown option to the labels.

https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher

Follow this link. It will be really helpful for all who want to change the dropdown.